# Android: Notification cancels it's repeating alarm

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I want my notification to cancel it's own repeating alarm. However, I don't know how to pass pendingIntent (to cancel it later) before it is even created.

Alarms sets here:

```
public class Schedule extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wakeLock.acquire();

        //next is notification code. //

        ...

        //create intent.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                NOTIFY_ID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        ...

        ////
        wakeLock.release();
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context) {

        ...

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Schedule.class);
        intent.putExtra("DELAY", delay);
        intent.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID", id);
        intent.putExtra("TITLE_TEXT", titleText);
        intent.putExtra("BIG_TEXT", bigText);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * delay, 1000 * 60 * delay, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

The key problem is that I want to cancel the repeating alarm on notification click (intent in onRecieve method), but canceling alarms requires pendingIntent, which notification is a part of. Any way to cheat the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager.cancel()` to `cancel` the specific `alarm` and use same `PendingIntent` that was used to create the alarm. Of course, you should use same `requestCode`(`NOTIFY_ID`) that was used before.

**Try this:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Schedule.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, NOTIFY_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Add this code portion into your MainActivty's `onCreate()` method as your `notification` will intent to `MainActivity` when `click` on it from notification panel.

Hope this will help~

Comment: Hello again :) I saw this answer already here (of course I've tried to google it before asking). But the problem is that method cancel() requires pendingIntent which is created after notification is passed to it. Or I can simply create pendingIntent with same ID to be able to cancel it? If so, it is marvelous. I will try it soon, thank you so much :)

Comment: This does not work :( I did just as you said and notification keep showing after clicks.

Comment: Make sure you are using same notification id for canceling notification. Do you wan to remove notification from panel when click on notification?

Comment: it will be removed anyway. All I want is to create repeated alarm that shows notification until the notification is clicked. Yep, I passed id there. I will debug it now and if I won't write anything that means that problem exists.

Comment: Now it works. Thank mate! The problem is odd, however. I have if-else switch and it was always triggering default 'false'. used if (true) and it worked :D You deserve a medal. Thank you so mush :)

Comment: Glad to know that. If my answer seems useful then you can mark it as right answer. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As you have privileges for upvote. If my answer helps then please give an up-vote too.